# Is there any software to find lookalike image in PDFs?

Tags: pdf, search, image

I have a cropped screenshot of complicated math equation (digitised), which I can't find in a pdf file containing it just by simply typing the equation in the find box of the pdf viewer (because it is a complicated math equation, which has to be written the Latex, which can't be written in the search box).

Is there any software in which I give the PDF file containing the math equation and the cropped screenshot of the equation, and the software will automatically detect on which page the same looking image is situated?

Please note that, **it's not about the digitization of a image only pdf by OCR**. Can anyone please help me to find such tool?

Answer (score 0):

Your best shot is to extract the pdf images and use image search.

extract images e.g. with https://tools.pdf24.org/en/extract-images

Recommendations for such software [here](https://superuser.com/questions/311633/free-visual-similarity-image-for-a-local-hard-drive-search)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).